# Getting handle to the setting window of Edge browser

Tags: c, winapi, window, msdn, z-order

In Edge browser, how can I get the handle to the settings window, once I have the handle to the browser itself?
[image]

I've tried to use `GetNextWindow(m_browserHndl, GW_HWDPREV)` API but it returns something else.

Comment: I doubt you'll be able to do this. Microsoft wants you to stop hacking at the browser. You should never have started doing so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *More actions* menu doesn't create a native window. The fact that it's **always** rendered inside the browser window is a strong indication for that. If you need certainty, use the [Inspect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318521.aspx) tool (part of the Windows SDK).

If you wish to automate the browser, use the supported automation interface instead. Microsoft Edge exposes the interfaces required to use [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009.aspx).